# Create database in memory from sql/csv files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, memory

I am creating a product that as end result will/can create e.g. 10 .sql files, each being a table. The tables will contain various pre-calculated data related to each other.

My users will need to upload these to their website (php, asp, whatever) and will need to make something useful. Only problem, the users may have next to zero understanding of databases, server-side code etc. This means it must be very easy to configure.

So I think thinking upload these .sql (or CSV files, whatever) tables to server, so they are *publicly* available (i.e. can be retrieved like any other public URL). And then find a Javascript in-memory database engine that can load .sql database files. Does this exist?

I imagine a Javascript solution could work well if amount of data could be kept somewhat down... Otherwise I may need to look for a PHP/ASP solution as well. (Any ideas for libraries that can init in-memory databases from .sql or similar files?)

Preferably I should be able to re-distribute this Javascript library. (So users can get a complete "directory" of .sql files + example page + Javascript database engine to upload)

So to make the question clear: Anyone knows a **Javascript-based in-memory database engine that can run inside browser?**

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried searching Google users a variety of search-phrases and found nothing that fits my needs, not even closely. (As stated in the question, I can *not* use solutions that depend on e.g. mysql, mssql, php, asp or anything like that!)

Comment: Why not converting the SQL files to JSON before uploading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use javascript and need some 'userfriendly' bridge database, you could use json or xml, because the format are simple text files (like csv as well) for wich you can find smart small editors for your users.
More json is made for javascript parsing and has an understanding tree format, but you should load only some part of sql datas in memory, saying data buffers in xml or json, with php requested with some javascript ajax call. Php do the sql database access work and then you can output json, and with javascript, it is for user's interface, you'll be able to display them.

Comment: All server-side stuff is a no-no. So that excludes PHP, Python, Ajax :)

I am looking for a pure in-memory Javascript database engine (not necessarily SQL compatible). 

My users are *not* going to be editing the data in any way either.

I will try look into if JSon/Javascript might be a solution. But I doubt JSon has ability to connect different "tables" of data together and do joins etc. like a database engine

Comment: I understand, that's quite a limit, it's like any client play it in local html without any server ;) anyway JSON is only a text format, it can't perform any request...this suggestion is just one way to store the datas differently so javascript can parse easily. I heared about jsonP also, don't know what it is yet...

Comment: It is an interesting idea simply to generate one big (as small as possible) Javascript file with all data directly accessible in JSon. It will ofcourse require me write the JS code using those data structures, but distribution-wise it would be easier with one file. (with data + code in a single .js file)

I will research your suggestions as a possible alternative to a JS in-memory database engine library if that idea fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql to store a database in memory:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: I will check it out! But the reason I am trying for a pure JavaScript solution is that I have no idea what my users will have access to (or knowledge to use) of php, asp, mssql, mysql etc. I can make no assumptions really :)

Comment: Are you going to use javascript in the browser or maybe node.js? I would recommend using python (you can bundle it with your app).

Comment: Javascript inside the browser is the solution I am looking for! :)

Comment: (However, I did also mention about PHP as backup solution if I could not find a inside-browser javascript in-memory database engine. And PHP/MySql is pretty common setup there! So thanks! will check it out.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JS SQL engine that stores everything in memory, https://github.com/moxley/sqittle

It flatly denies being useful for anything though, and has a limited set of supported commands (see readme on above link.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look at it :) It would be great if I could fine a pure Javascript in-memory database engine :)

Answer (score 0):

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

That question seems very old. You might want to look at [LokiJS](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS) now.